# Pagination jQuery next and previous control with keyboard - .trigger('click') doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on pagination.

To help a user to change pages with keyboard short-keys, instead of clicking a mouse, I came up with a jQuery solution that catches user keyboard events with `CTRL + →` and `CTRL+ ←`

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey) { // if ctrl is being held
      var keycode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
        if(keycode === 39) { // for rightwards arrow (for leftwards arrow keycode === 37)
           window.open($('#pagination li.next a').attr('href'), '_parent'); // open the next link
            }
  }
});
```

My question is why it doesn't work with regular `.trigger('click')`, like this:

```
$('#pagination li.next a').trigger('click');
```

Comment: where have you bind that to happen with click?

Comment: @Ashirvad Singh: I tried, didn't work? Any examples you could provide?

Comment: did you try keyup instead of keydow?

Comment: Yes, just did, changes nothing.

Comment: `trigger()` only works when you bind an event with `jQuery`

Comment: then wait i will try to provide one example

Comment: Ok, will wait, thank you, Ashirvad Singh!

Comment: check my answer if that what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find the exact answer for my question, I would like to post a slightly different and final, well working solution, based on information gathered and peoples' post. Thank you those that replied!

When you construct pagination, I believe, a user would be happy to just click ← Ctrl / Ctrl → to switch in between pages.

The following code has only one improvement - the error occurred on the first an the last page - when there are no next or previous buttons on the page, because you either on the last pagination or the first one, the initial code returned undefined (obviously), so I fixed it and would like to share the final result with those who could be possibly interested:

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
var keycode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
  if (event.ctrlKey) {
    if (keycode === 39) {
        var nextExists = $('#pagination li.next a').attr('href');
        if (nextExists) window.location.href = $('#pagination li.next a').attr("href");
    }
    if (keycode === 37) {
        var previousExists = $('#pagination li.previous a').attr('href');
        if (previousExists) window.location.href = $('#pagination li.previous a').attr("href");
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[jsFiddle Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QHbRg/3/)

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com', '_blank');
});

$('#prev').click(function() {
    window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');
});

$(function() {
    $('#next').trigger('click')
})
```

Comment: No, my friend, it's not what I was asking. Please let me explain again. `window.open($('#pagination li.next a').attr('href'), '_parent')` happens when a user clicks CTRL+Leftwards, and he/she is being taken too the other (next or previous) page. Remember I'm talking about pagination, look here at the bottom of the page: http://stackoverflow.com/badges/222/altruist. I just wanted to replace `window.open($('#pagination li.next a').attr('href')` with jQuery working solution. As it appeared it's not going to work just with jQuery, making less codes but on contrary.Thanks a lot for your post anyway